# Why is SparkContext being shutdown during Logistic Regression?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I think it has something to do with memory, because it was working fine for smaller data sets. The program utilizes, and prematurely shuts down, while using Logistic Regression from Spark-Mllib. I am running this command below to start my spark program on HDFS.

```
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/home/gs/conf/spark/latest
export SPARK_HOME=/home/gs/spark/latest

$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class algoRunner --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
 --executor-memory 8g  --queue default --conf spark.hadoop.hive.querylog.location='${java.io.tmpdir}/hivelogs' \
~/spark/Product-Classifier-Pipeline-assembly-1.0.jar
```

I receive the following error:

```
17/08/02 21:53:40 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/08/02 21:53:40 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/08/02 21:53:40 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://gsrd219n01.red.ygrid.yahoo.com:45546
17/08/02 21:53:40 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 10 failed: treeAggregate at LogisticRegression.scala:1670, took 2.351935 s
17/08/02 21:53:40 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 19 (treeAggregate at LogisticRegression.scala:1670) failed in 1.947 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
17/08/02 21:53:40 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@21bec75d)
17/08/02 21:53:40 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(10,1501710820713,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 10 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down))
17/08/02 21:53:40 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 10 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 10 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver memory wasn't large enough. Increasing it prevented these errors.